# Loss value jumps when trained model is saved and restored with tf.train.Saver()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

**EDIT:**

The original title of this post was

"Loss value jumps when learning rate is decreased, then comes back down slowly"

however I now think this happens when the saved model is restored, regardless of whether or not the learning rate is changed or not.

After 10 epochs with a learning rate of 0.001, the loss reached ~10. I then saved and restored the model, recommenced training and the loss for the 11th epoch was ~15. It did not reach 10 again for another 5 epochs.

---

I have built an Autoencoder model as shown below. It uses `tf.train.Saver()` to save and restore the trained model to/from memory. I have the learning rate as a `tf.placeholder`, thus allowing it to be specified in the `feed_dict`.

When training the model, I initially begin with a higher learning rate, let it train until the loss begins to plateau, then save the model, manually reduce the learning rate, restore it and recommence training.

However, when this change happens, the loss always jumps far higher than it as prior to the change, and then slowly but consistently reduces again. I cannot understand why this jump would happen, unless there is something wrong with my implementation.

```
import os
import pickle as pk

import tensorflow as tf


class Autoencoder:

    def __init__(self, encoderDims, sparseInput=False, tiedWeights=False, denoise=False):
        self.encoderDims = encoderDims
        self.decoderDims = list(reversed(encoderDims))
        self.sparseInput = sparseInput
        self.tiedWeights = tiedWeights
        self.denoise = denoise          # Only works for greyscale image data

        self.input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, encoderDims[0]])
        self.learningRate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [])

        self.activationFunction = tf.nn.sigmoid             # TO DO: Allow to be specified by user
        # self.activationFunction = tf.tanh
        # self.activationFunction = tf.nn.selu
        self.SGD = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learningRate)

        if self.denoise:
            self.__addNoise()
        self.__buildNetwork()           # Constructs Encoder & Decoder
        self.__buildTensorFlowGraph()   # Creates sequential TensorFlow operations

        self.session = tf.Session()
        self.session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  # Initialise weights & biases
        self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
        self.session.graph.finalize()   # Avoids memory leaks through duplicating graph nodes

    def __addNoise(self):
        # Create a tensor of random numbers with unit variance
        # Then sets pixels to black where values of random tensor > 1
        # (i.e. all values outside the std dev -> ~32% of pixels)
        random = tf.random_normal(tf.shape(self.input))
        mask = tf.greater(random, 1.0)
        self.noisyInput = tf.where(
            mask, tf.ones_like(self.input) * 255, self.input)

    def __buildNetwork(self):
        # Lists of weights and biases per layer of encoder and decoder
        self.encoderWeights, self.encoderBiases = [], []
        self.decoderWeights, self.decoderBiases = [], []
        for layer in range(len(self.encoderDims) - 1):
            self.encoderWeights.append(
                tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(
                    [self.encoderDims[layer], self.encoderDims[layer + 1]]))
            )
            self.encoderBiases.append(
                tf.Variable(tf.zeros([self.encoderDims[layer + 1]]))
            )
            # if layer != len(self.decoderDims) - 2:  # BIAS IN OUTPUT LAYER????
            self.decoderBiases.append(
                tf.Variable(tf.zeros([self.decoderDims[layer + 1]]))
            )
            if not self.tiedWeights:
                self.decoderWeights.append(
                    tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(
                        [self.decoderDims[layer], self.decoderDims[layer + 1]]))
                )
        if self.tiedWeights:
            self.decoderWeights = [tf.transpose(
                i) for i in reversed(self.encoderWeights)]

    def __buildTensorFlowGraph(self):
        self.encoded = self.encode()        # Encoded/compressed data
        self.decoded = self.decode()        # Decoded/reconstructed data
        self.loss = self.__calculateLoss()
        self.train = self.SGD.minimize(self.loss)

    def encode(self):
        if self.denoise:
            encoded = self.noisyInput
        else:
            encoded = self.input
        for layer in range(len(self.encoderDims) - 1):
            encoded = tf.matmul(encoded, self.encoderWeights[layer])
            encoded = tf.add(encoded, self.encoderBiases[layer])
            # if layer != len(self.encoderDims) - 2:    # KEEP LAST LINEAR?
            encoded = self.activationFunction(encoded)
        return encoded

    def decode(self):
        decoded = self.encoded
        for layer in range(len(self.decoderDims) - 1):
            decoded = tf.matmul(decoded, self.decoderWeights[layer])
            # if layer != len(self.decoderDims) - 2:  # BIAS IN OUTPUT LAYER????
            decoded = tf.add(decoded, self.decoderBiases[layer])
            if layer != len(self.decoderDims) - 2:  # Keep output layer linear
                decoded = self.activationFunction(decoded)
        return decoded

    def __calculateLoss(self):
        # TO DO: ADD REGULARISATION
        if self.sparseInput:
            nonZeros = tf.where(tf.greater(self.input, 0))
            input = tf.gather(self.input, nonZeros)
            output = tf.gather(self.decoded, nonZeros)
        else:
            input = self.input
            output = self.decoded

        return tf.sqrt(
            tf.losses.mean_squared_error(
                labels=input,
                predictions=output
            )
        )

    def setBatch(self, input, learningRate=0.0):
        self.batchDict = {
            self.input: input,
            self.learningRate: learningRate
        }

    def run(self, operations=None, train=False):
        # Returns values of specified list of operations
        # Trains network's parameters if specified
        if not type(operations) is list:
            operations = [operations]

        if train:
            ops = [self.train]
        else:
            ops = []

        if operations is not None:
            for op in operations:
                if op == 'input':
                    ops.append(self.input)
                if op == 'noisyInput':
                    ops.append(self.noisyInput)
                if op == 'encoded':
                    ops.append(self.encoded)
                if op == 'decoded':
                    ops.append(self.decoded)
                if op == 'loss':
                    ops.append(self.loss)

        if (train and len(ops) == 2) or (not train and len(ops) == 1):
            return self.session.run(ops, self.batchDict)[-1]
        elif train:
            return self.session.run(ops, self.batchDict)[1:]
        else:
            return self.session.run(ops, self.batchDict)

    def save(self, epoch, modelName="Autoencoder"):
        modelName += '.ckpt'
        dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/SavedModels/'
        self.saver.save(self.session, dir + modelName)
        loss = self.session.run(self.loss, self.batchDict)
        with open(dir + modelName + '_epoch.pk', 'wb') as epochFile:
            pk.dump(epoch, epochFile)
        with open(dir + modelName + '_loss.pk', 'wb') as lossFile:
            pk.dump(loss, lossFile)

    def restore(self, modelName="Autoencoder"):
        modelName += '.ckpt'
        dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/SavedModels/'
        self.saver.restore(self.session, dir + modelName)
        with open(dir + modelName + '_epoch.pk', 'rb') as epochFile:
            epoch = pk.load(epochFile)
        with open(dir + modelName + '_loss.pk', 'rb') as lossFile:
            loss = pk.load(lossFile)
        return epoch, loss

    def kill(self):
        self.session.close()
```

Here is a how the model is trained:

```
import os

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
from Autoencoder import Autoencoder

loadModel = True
# loadModel = False
learningRate = 0.001
numEpochs = 10000
batchSize = 1  # Divide into 670
printStep = 1

projectDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

# (671, 9066)
original = pd.read_csv(projectDir + '/Data/ratings_small_pivoted.csv').drop('userId', axis=1)
numSamples = original.shape[0]
numFeatures = original.shape[1]
numBatches = numSamples // batchSize

encoderDims = [
    numFeatures,
    numFeatures // 2
]

ae = Autoencoder(encoderDims, sparseInput=True)

if loadModel:
    bestEpoch, bestLoss = ae.restore()
else:
    bestEpoch, bestLoss = 0, 9999

for epoch in range(1, numEpochs - bestEpoch + 1):
    epochLoss = 0
    for batch in range(numBatches):
        batchInput = original[batch * batchSize: (batch + 1) * batchSize]
        ae.setBatch(batchInput, learningRate)
        batchLoss = ae.run(['loss'], train=True)
        epochLoss += batchLoss
    epochLoss /= numBatches
    if epochLoss < bestLoss:
        bestLoss = epochLoss
        ae.save(epoch + bestEpoch)
    if epoch == 1 or epoch % printStep == 0:
        print("EPOCH: {} / {}".format(epoch + bestEpoch, numEpochs))
        print("LOSS:  {} ({})\n".format("%.4f" % epochLoss, "%.4f" % bestLoss))
```

[Here is the data I am using.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12e1kUjhTVR7NzzyvLXWY5Gkqs6MBS9WF/view?usp=sharing)

With a learning rate of 0.001, the loss reaches ~1.0 after 100 epochs. I then reduce it to 0.0001 and the loss immediately jumps to ~3.9 on the first epoch, then consistently decreases after this epoch, but very slowly.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? Someone else appears to be experiencing something similar (albeit using PyTorch instead of Tensorflow) here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/8063/1641